# What type of surface mount diode is SOT-23 marked "JY L"?

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount, sot23

What type of surface mount diode is this, SOT-23 marked "JY L"

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part is most likely a BAV199L dual diode, datasheet [here](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/bav199lt1-d.pdf).

The key marking is JY, with L probably being a date code.  There are several manufacturers who make this part with a JY code including Nexperia and OnSemi.

The date coding and exact locations are a good match for the OnSemi part (as noted by nanash1 in comments), as is the "dot".  However, whilst I'm pretty confident of the part id, specific manufacturer typically remains uncertain on SOT23 parts unless you see the specific logo (which we don't have in this case).

Here's a photo from an eBay advert for the onsemi part.

[image]

Comment: The 90° rotated date code is used by [onsemi](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Diodes-General-Purpose_onsemi-BAV199LT1G_C145516.html).

Comment: @nanash1 Thanks.  I've updated the answer.